# ¿mi pregunta es como puedo sobre escribir un archivo?

Tags: c#

Lo que tengo en el programa es un archivo ya creado que tiene el id ya agregado el numero de sala
el dia ya esta agregado y la hora igual ademas ya tiene agregado los dos horarios primeros con
el nombre del titulo de la exposicion y el nombre del ponente mi duda es como poner los demas titulos
de las exposiciones y el nombre de los ponentes  en un archivo de txt sobreescribiendo el mismo arcivo la primera parte del codigo es la siguiente

[image: este es la imgen]

Aqui esta el codgio siguiente con el archivo txt aqui lo que esta haciendo el programa es leer el archivo ya creado

```
 Console.WriteLine("\t\tLista de Horarios: ");
        string nombreArchivoLeer = name; //Como hacer para que el usuario ingrese el nombre del archivo??????
        StreamReader leerArchivo = new StreamReader(nombreArchivoLeer);
        string linea = leerArchivo.ReadLine(); //Leo la primera línea
        string[] lineas = new string[100];
        int contador = 0;
        //nombreArchivoLeer = "8D21.txt";
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nombreArchivoLeer);
            //leo y verifico que no sea null (archivo vacío)

            while ((linea = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineas[contador] = linea;
                //Console.WriteLine(linea);
                contador++;
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error al leer el archivo: " + e.Message);
        }
        string[] idSala = new string[contador];  
        string[] sala = new string[contador]; 
        string[] dia = new string[contador]; 
        string[] hora = new string[contador];
        string[] titulo = new string[contador];
        string[] ponente = new string[contador];

        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
        {
            //Separar el contenido de la slíneas con split y guardar en el archivo
            string[] datos = lineas[i].Split('|');
            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    idSala[i] = datos[j]; 
                else if (j == 1)
                    sala[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 2)
                    dia[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 3)
                    hora[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 4)
                    titulo[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 5)
                    ponente[i] = datos[j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {2}, \tSala:{3}, \tDía: {4}, \tHora: {5}, \tTitulo: {6}, \tPonente: {7}\n",
                i + 1, i, idSala[i], sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
        }
```

Una vez que ya se lee archivo lo que sigue es pedirle al usurio que horario quiere escoger aqui esta la parte del codigo

```
 public void VerHorarios()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Indica el dia que nombre del archivo del dia que deceas ....: " +
           "\n Ingrese '7D21.txt' Para el dia 7 de Dic" +
           "\n Ingrese '8D21.txt' para el dia 8 de Dic" +
           "\n Ingrese '9D21.txt' para el dia 9 de Dic" +
           "\n Ingrese '10D21.txt' para el día 10 de Dic");

        string sala = Console.ReadLine();
        int horario = 0;
        switch (sala)
        {
            case "7D21.txt":
                Horario read1 = new Horario();
                read1.leer("7D21.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                    "\n1) 9 a 11 am" +
                    "\n2) 11 a 13:00 am" +
                    "\n3) 13 a 2 pm " +
                    "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                    "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                    "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
                horario = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (horario)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Esta ocupado este horario");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese otro horario");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Esta ocupado este horario");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese otro horario");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el titutlo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                }

                break;
            case "8D21.txt":
                Horario read2 = new Horario();
                read2.leer("8D21.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                   "\n1) 9 a 10 am" +
                   "\n2) 10 a 11:30 am" +
                   "\n3) 12 a 2 pm " +
                   "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                   "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                   "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
                horario = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (horario)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                }

                break;
            case "9D21.txt":
                Horario read3 = new Horario();
                read3.leer("9D21.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                   "\n1) 9 a 10 am" +
                   "\n2) 10 a 11:30 am" +
                   "\n3) 12 a 2 pm " +
                   "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                   "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                   "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
                horario = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (horario)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                }

                break;
            case "10D21.txt":
                Horario read4 = new Horario();
                read4.leer("10D21.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                   "\n1) 9 a 10 am" +
                   "\n2) 10 a 11:30 am" +
                   "\n3) 12 a 2 pm " +
                   "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                   "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                   "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
                horario = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (horario)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Titulo de la ponencia");
                        tema = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("ingrese el nombre del ponente");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                }
                break;
```

Una vez que el usuario haya ingresado el titulo de la exposicion y el nombre del ponente se tiene que sobreescribir el archivo en las casillas titulo el nombre del titulo de la exposicion que el usuario ingreso y en las casillas ponente el nombre del ponente espero me halla explicado bien
"""

Comment: gracias por responder mi duda

Comment: y tener muchos comentarios

Comment: Por favor, recuerda que los signos de puntuación _existen_ :) Y el título de la pregunta es si tu pregunta es acerca de cómo sobreescribir un archivo: respondiendo tal cual está, la respuesta es _al parecer, sí_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por otra parte, como observación: ¿por qué hacés un `switch` de _horario_, si cada `case` es exactamente igual? (a excepción del primer `case` "más grande").

Comment: ¿Leíste [esta pregunta](/q/463611)?